# Why does Keybase not include my public PGP key fingerprint in my GitHub proof?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, keybase

I have set up a Keybase identity and added my PGP public key.

When validating my GitHub identity the text Keybase provides me includes the line
`I have a public key ASCBCvhvoS0FhnkV48BJpopPPCfcC5QGdrTZCpuQgETcswo`.

When viewing the GitHub proof of others, for example [vbuterin](https://gist.github.com/vbuterin/5ea831f79fd6543306e751a5e0f4f447), they instead have the line
`I have a public key whose fingerprint is...`
with the fingerprint of their PGP key.

**Why doesn't keybase use my public PGP key here?**
I was expecting to be able to use this mechanism to prove my PGP key, as others do

**What did this public key come from?**
I haven't been able to find `ASCBCvhvoS0FhnkV48BJpopPPCfcC5QGdrTZCpuQgETcswo` anywhere on my Keybase account or in my PGP key, where did this come from?

Comment: Apologies, I have seen this done before and found use in it so didn't realise it wasn't meant to be done this way.
Should I edit it out and replace with an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Keybase proofs aren't for linking your GitHub account to your PGP key anymore – they're for linking your GitHub account to your *Keybase account*. The difference is that the latter may now be represented using Keybase-specific "device keys" and "paper keys", in addition to the PGP key.

Every time you run `keybase login` or sign into the app, a new device key is generated and used for all operations, instead of the PGP key.

(If you click "2 devices" on your Keybase profile, you'll be able to see the full trust graph of your account – everything *can* be linked to your PGP key, but sometimes it takes two or three links.)

I don't know the advantages of this scheme, that's just how they implemented it.

It is still possible to make PGP-based signatures; e.g. when performing operations directly in the website you'll be prompted to run a gpg|curl command to generate the proof.

Comment: So is this public key my *account* key, or my *device* key?

Comment: If you used the desktop app or CLI to generate the proof, it used a "device" key. If you used the website to generate the proof, it usually uses the PGP key, but it _might_ be using an "account" key.

Comment: Looking at the [sigchain](https://keybase.io/benji7425/sigchain) and the [graph](https://keybase.io/benji7425/graph), it says the GitHub proof was made using a _device_ key called "Friday".

Comment: Thanks for the details, using the browser provides a way to generate a proof by signing the provided object with my PGP key locally.
I feel this is preferrable, as it allows people to visually double check my keyserver key with my gist.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [answer by @grawity](https://superuser.com/a/1420443/1010768) I have learned that Keybase uses the Keybase device key for the device which was used to generate the proof.

You can generate the proof with your PGP key by using a browser to create the proof, choosing the Bash + GPG + cURL method when prompted. This will provide you with a command to sign a message and send it to keybase with the provided curl command. You can see my updated proof [here](https://gist.github.com/benji7425/a13bdd15c4cc76b5b965f947f3676337).

Note that it appears you need to use bash for this, using curl in PowerShell was giving me issues.